# Ruby On Rails - Coverting a JOIN using HAVING to a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

I tried to ask this question previously and it didn't go well - hopefully I do it better this time.

I have three models

```
class Flavor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :components
  has_many :ingredients, through: :components
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :components
  has_many :flavors, through: :components
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :flavor

  validates :percentage, presence: true 
end
```

Batches are made of flavors, but a flavor can only be made into a batch if it's components add up to 100 percent (hence why I put the percentage validation in there so it was represented).

At first I tried to write this as a scope, but could never get it to work, the model testing i created worked using

```
def self.batch_eligible
  self.find_by_sql("Select flavors.* FROM flavors 
  INNER JOIN components on flavors.id = components.flavor_id 
  GROUP BY flavors.id, flavors.name 
  HAVING SUM(percentage)=100")
end
```

I did make an attempt at the scope and it failed.  Here is the final version of the scope I came up with:

`scope :batch_eligible, -> {joins(:components).having('SUM(percentage) = 100').group('flavor.id')}`

The resultant object will be used to populate a selection list in a form for batches (flavors can exist before the components are fully worked out).

I figure the limitation here is my understanding of scopes - so how would the scope be built properly to produce the same results as the find_by_sql expression?

All help is appreciated, thanks.

In response to the first comment - I tried a variety of scopes without capturing the errors - the scope above returns this error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "flavor"
   LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, flavor.id AS flavor_id FROM "f...
                                         ^
   : SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, flavor.id AS flavor_id FROM "flavors" INNER JOIN "components" ON "components"."flavor_id" = "flavors"."id" GROUP BY flavor.id HAVING SUM(percentage) = 100
```

changing it to flavors id makes it 'work' but it doesn't return the proper information.

One more piece of code - models testing

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Flavor, type: :model do
  let!(:flavor) {FactoryGirl.create(:flavor)}
  let!(:flavor2) {FactoryGirl.create(:flavor)}
  let!(:ingredient) {FactoryGirl.create(:ingredient)}
  let!(:component) {FactoryGirl.create(:component, flavor: flavor, ingredient: ingredient, percentage: 25)}
  let!(:component1) {FactoryGirl.create(:component, flavor: flavor2, ingredient: ingredient, percentage: 100)}

  it "should have a default archive as false" do
    expect(flavor.archive).to be(false)
  end

  it "should only have valid flavors for batch creation" do
    expect(Flavor.batch_eligible.count).to eq 1
    expect(Flavor.batcH_eligible.first).to eq flavor2
  end
end
```

Even with a clean test database - the batch_eligible count is 4 - not one

One more note - the tests DO pass with the find_by_sql function being used - I just think a scope should be possible?

Comment: What errors did you observe when you tried the version you have so far? Have you tried removing parts and seeing what the result are, to see that the pieces work independently? or which piece is the piece that breaks?

Comment: @TarynEast Please see above edit - regarding the error - how i tried to fix it in response to the error and still not working.  I really thought this would be an easy thing

Comment: ok, so re: complaining about the flavour_id thing... you might need to be explicit about what the columns belong to eg maybe try `joins(:components).references(:components).having('SUM(components.percentage) = 100').group('components.flavor_id')` Also I'd recommend not starting with `count` -> sometimes a complex scope works but rails has trouble converting it to a proper "count" query... start by making it return `.all` and then doing a `.size` on that (just to get it partly-working)... then figure out how to get `count` working properly.

Comment: Also - instead of testing count... try `puts`ing out the array of flavours, including the sum-percentage and see what you're getting and how it differs from the 1 you expect? Finally, use `to_sql` to see what it's trying to generate eg: `Flavor.batch_eligible.to_sql`

Comment: @TarynEast Thank you for all of that - i will give it a shot - though I don't fully understand it atll at this point - i haven't really tried anything this complex before :) - what does references do for instance?

Comment: Normally when rails builds a SQl query, it gives each db-table a code-name that is short (eg t3)... but if you're going to use the full table-name in one of the later methods (eg where we use `components.flavour_id`) then you need to tell rails that you're going to "reference the table name later"... ie `references` :)

Comment: @TarynEast I did not know that - thank you - as you'll see in the answer I put below - the references wasn't eligible but I can't thank you enough for the help because it did lead to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props to @taryneast for the help - I was pointed in the right direction by this.

After correcting the scope issue with flavors.id - I did run the inspect to see what was happening but I also ran a variety of functions.

`puts Flavor.batch_eligible.count` or `puts Flavor.batch_eligible.size` both yield the same thing, for example, the hash {312 => 1} - 312 would be the id of the Factory Created Flavor.

So the problem (once I solved flavors.id) wasn't in the scope - it was in the test.  You need to test the LENGTH, `Flavor.batch_eligible.length` yields the integer 1 that I wanted.

Perhaps everyone else knew that - I didn't.

Thank you Taryn